# Startup current for buck converter controller

Tags: buck

[In this Reference Design](https://www.ti.com/lit/df/tidrk45/tidrk45.pdf?ts=1590615980990), a buck converter was designed using the UCC28881 controller.

According to the datasheet, the HVIN pin is a current source, with an internal supply current of 58 uA typically. Also, the minimum voltage at this pin is 30V.

[image]

In the design above, the HVIN pin is connected to the VIN net, which is the cathode of diode D6+D7, after the string of resistors R6-R15. The design says the minimum input DC voltage is 235 VDC.

My question is:
If I want the design to operate with lower DC voltage, that is, 100 VDC, what modification would I need to do? Would that string of resistors allow enough current for the HVIN pin at the minimum voltage? The diodes comes into play when bus voltage is >500V, so below 500V, the voltage at HVIN pin is the same as the bus voltage, right?

I'd appreciate any guidance to further understand the input side of this circuit.

Comment: Are you aware how dangerous this type of supply is?

Comment: If you're talking about it not being isolated, and high input voltage, yes I'm aware.